# Why display:block and display:inline both exists in one css file?

Tags: html, css

```
.nav ul li a:hover{ 
background:url(../images/left.png) no-repeat left top;
 height:43px; 
 display:block;
 padding:0px 13px 0px 13px;
 margin:-3px -25px 0px 0px;
 position:relative; 
 float:left; 
 display:inline;
 color:#FFF; 
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

this css file use both display:block;and display:inline; 
Do u konw why?

Comment: Also float make no sense either. This is just bad code.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely an example of **what not to do** with CSS. It could be the author decided to use a different display mode and forgot to remove the previous one, or just plain negligence, but the mix of floats and display modes points to someone who doesn't know what they are doing.

Either they are learning CSS or simply added on properties until it worked without understanding why.

Answer (score 0):

This is either plain bad practice or an error from a tired developer, and should never be repeated. It is still, however, valid, even if nonsensical.

According to [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> When specificity is equal to any of the multiple declarations, the last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element.

Because of this, the `display:block;` part will be completely ignored, by being overridden by the later declared `display:inline;`, and can be safely removed.